# Get UITextView Gesture (To Identify Location of Tap/LongPress)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, location, uitextview

I'm rather confident [editable] UITextView's become firstResponder when a long press or tap gesture occurs within the scrollView. I want to identify where in the view this touch occured. Digging through the documentation and source code didn't yield me much. I might be going about this wrong. My concern is a race condition if I just add my own tap recognizer (how can I be sure it is called before the textView's delegate methods).

For practical clarification, I want to call two similar functions from a delegate function (editingDidBegin) but depending if they touched the left or right half of the text view, I want to call either of the two.